# Initializing an array of objects

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm currently working on a card game, and I'm having trouble with some initialization code:

```
// in my class...
Card cards[20];
// in method...
for(int i = 0; i <= 20;i++)
    cards++ = new Card(i, /*i as char +*/ "_Card.bmp");
```

The trouble is that my compiler's telling me that `cards++` is not an l-value.  I've read up on the whole pointer-array equivalence thing, and I thought I understood it, but alas, I can't get it to work.  My understanding is that since `cards` degrades to a pointer, and the `new` operator gives me a pointer to the location of my new instance of Card, then the above code should compile.  Right?

I've tried using a subscript as well, but isn't `cards+i`, `cards++`, and `cards[i]` just 3 ways of saying the same thing?  I thought that each of those were l-values and are treated as pointers.

Comment: cards+i returns cards+i; cards++ increments cards by one; cards[i] returns a reference to the i'th element in cards. They are all different.

Answer (score 27):

```
Card cards[20];
```

`cards` is already an array of objects. They are constructed with the default constructor(constructor with no arguments). There is no need to `new` again.  Probably you need a member function equivalent to constructor arguments and assign through it.

```
for ( int i=0; i<20; ++i ) // array index shouldn't include 20
   cards[i].memberFunction(/*....*/);
```

Even simpler is to use `std::vector`

```
std::vector<Card> cards;
for( int i=0; i<20; ++i )
    cards.push_back(Card(i, /*i as char +*/ "_Card.bmp"); )
```

Comment: I figured a vector would be a better idea.  So I tried using a vector, but now I'm getting something I have been running into a alot:  Once I included <vector>, I get a list of insane-looking "unresolved externals" errors from libcpmtd.lib.  This tells me there's nothing wrong with MY code, but I still won't compile... Ugh.

Comment: I you wish to use std::vector and now the number of element to be added, DO NOT USE push_back: The overhead is small but avoidable.
You should initialize the vector at the right size 'std::vector<Card> cards(20);' and then initialize the members the same way you did for the Array.

Comment: @Clodéric You could also address the inefficiency of `push_back` by simply pre-allocating the vector: `std::vector<Card> cards; cards.reserve(20);`  This enables calling `emplace_back` with your custom constructor arguments via perfect forwarding: `cards.emplace_back(i, /*i as char +*/ "_Card.bmp");`. This seems more readable/maintainable since it uses constructors instead of mandatory initialization methods.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to avoid unnecessary constructor calls *and* unnecessary resizing, then it's more complicated, because C++ normally initialises each objects one-by-one as it's allocated. One workaround is to do it the Java way -- use a loop and an array of pointers, like so:

```
Card *cards[20];
for (int i=0; i<20; i++) {
  cards[i] = new Card(i);
}
```

Another option is to use malloc to get explicitly uninitialized memory:

```
Card *cards = malloc(20 * sizeof(Card));
for (int i=0; i<20; i++) {
  new (&(cards[i])) Card(i);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The code `Card cards[20];` already creates an array of 20 `Card` objects and creates them with the default constructor. This may not be what you want given your code.

I would suggest using `vector` instead.

```
std::vector<Card> cards;

for(int i = 0; i < 20;i++)
{
    cards.push_back(Card(i, /*i as char +*/ "_Card.bmp"));
}
```

Note that your `for` loop goes from `0` to `20` and thus one past the end of the array.

Answer (score 4):

Well, there is another possibility, when you are ok with your constructors being called automatically at initialization:

```
// in my class...
Card cards[20] = { Card(0, "0_Card.bmp"), Card(1, "1_Card.bmp"), /* ... */ };
```

The huge downside is that you cannot use a loop in this case.

Answer (score 2):

An array name, `cards` in your code, contains the **address** of the first element of the array. Such addresses are allocated at run time and you cannot change them. Hence the compiler complaining about `cards` being not an l-value.

But you can definitely specify what those addresses can hold by using a pointer like below:

```
// in my class...
Card cards[20];

Card *cardsPointer = cards;// Pointer contains the address of the
//1st element of 'cards' array.

// in method...
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
*(cardsPointer++) = Card(i, /*i as char +*/ "_Card.bmp");// Note that 
// there is no 'new' operator as 'cardsPointer' has type 'Card *' and 
// not 'Card **'. And 'cardsPointer' has type 'Card *' as the array is
// of type 'Card'.
```